# Overflow in the "sort by" drop down list when searching via the SE blog

Tags: bug, design, blog

Steps to reproduce:

1. Go to [the SE blog](https://blog.stackexchange.com/)
2. Type anything in the search box in the right side.
3. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> or click the <kbd>Search</kbd> button.

Result:

[image: SCREENSHOT]